# Google Forms Apps Script (hover text not appearing nicely until refresh)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a working Google Apps script which is setting the helpText on an image item like this:

```js
      form.addImageItem()
        .setImage(questionImages[i])
        .setTitle("Question " + position)
        .setHelpText(question.help)
```

This all works fine. The problem is that the help text can be *quite long* and when I insert it into the form it looks incorrectly sized ->

[image: ugly hover]

Until the page is refreshed, and then it is correctly sized and displays nicely ->

[image: better display]

Is there a way to force the page to "redraw"? I attempted to "refresh" the page with:

```js
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var id = form.getId();
  FormApp.openById(id);
```

but that did not work. I haven't seen any kind of "refresh" or similar function in the [api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app), so, I'm out of ideas.

If anyone has solved this issue I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could replicate the same situation. In this case, it seems that when Google Fomr service (FormApp) is used, such a situation occurs.

But, fortunately, I could confirm that when Google Forms API is used, all texts can be shown when the long texts are put. So in this answer, I would like to propose the method for using Forms API.

### Usage:

#### 1. Linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE.

In order to use Forms API, please link Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE, and please enable Forms API at API console. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE)

#### 2. Sample script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const formId = "###"; // Please set your Google Form ID.

  const url = `https://forms.googleapis.com/v1beta/forms/${formId}:batchUpdate`;
  const requestBody = {
    "requests": [
      {
        "createItem": {
          "item": {
            "imageItem": {
              "image": {
                "sourceUri": "https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png",
                "altText": "sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample"
              }
            },
            "title": "sample title"
          },
          "location": {
            "index": 0
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  const params = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    payload: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

- In this script, please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.body`.

### Note:

- **When you want to simply check this, you can also use ["Try this method" of Forms API](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/batchUpdate). In this case, please put the request body using my proposed script. By this, you can test it soon.**

### References:

- [Linking Google Cloud Platform Project to Google Apps Script Project for New IDE](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE)
- [Method: forms.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms/batchUpdate)

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh! there's a Google Forms API now!!! this is very exciting (and didn't exist when we first built out this plugin). I'll look into that.

Comment: @patrickdavey Thank you for replying. Yes. Google Forms API has released on March 16, 2022. This is the newer API. When this Forms API is used, the situation which cannot be achieved with Form Service (FormApp) can be achieved. I think that your goal is one of them.